# How to disable PyCharm pending snap update notifications?

Tags: python, kubuntu, notifications, snap

I often see messages from snapd indicating that PyCharm has an upcoming update (see example attached below), and I'd like to prevent these from appearing on my desktop.

PyCharm is the only application for which this occurs, though I do have a few other packages installed via snap such as Firefox and Spotify.

My OS is Kubuntu 20.04.

[image: Pending update for PyCharm from snap service]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to a new feature of the snap service, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store). Various fixes are suggested in that answer, essentially it's to kill the app and then run a snap refresh.